# Why does this not return a boolean

Tags: javascript

I have inherited some javascript which has this line:

```
var vehicle = data.vehicles && data.vehicles.length > 0 && data.vehicles[0];
```

This returns the data.vehicles[0] object, not true or false. Why?

Comment: Why would you expect it to return a boolean?

Comment: The `&&` operator in JavaScript works in a way that's significantly different than the similar operator in other languages.

Comment: please share with us values of your variables

Comment: you can use `var vehicle = data.vehicles && data.vehicles.length > 0 && !!data.vehicles[0];` if you want the statement to return a boolean

Comment: Or `var vehicle = !! (data.vehicles && data.vehicles.length > 0 && data.vehicles[0]);`, but there's rarely a *need* to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` and `||` don't return booleans exclusively. `&&` returns the last truthy value (or the first falsey) and `||` returns the first truthy value or the last falsey.

Comment: The rules table [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) explains it pretty well: `expr1 && expr2`, *Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.*

Comment: *"`||` returns the first falsey value."* So, what does `true || false` return?

Comment: @FelixKling, in that case the operator short-circuits and just returns true

Comment: @worc: But `true` is not a falsey value. According to the answer, `false` should be returned.

Comment: The explanation is not correct anyway. `&&` returns the left operand if it's falsy, and the right operand otherwise. `||` returns the left operand if it's truthy and the right otherwise.

Comment: yeah, it should be edited, i missed the the flipped logic

Comment: Apparently so did I.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vehicle = !!(data.vehicles && data.vehicles.length > 0 && data.vehicles[0]);
```

Hope this explanation help you:
[basic_truthy_falsy](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch01.html#basic_truthy_falsy)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I was more looking for an explanation of why it happens, not how to convert it to a bool :)